# How to pass object in the RequestBody to the annotation

Tags: java, spring, rest, annotations

I have a custom annotation which checks if the current user has the needed privileges which are passed as the annotation parameters. Theres one exception: If a user wants to change the data of another user, he has to have the higher rank. So I need to pass the ID of the user (or the user object) which should be changed. In the rest call below, that would be the ID of `userDto`. The problem is, I can't pass the `userDto.getId()` since `userDto` is not resolvable yet. See the code below:

Called method in the rest controller with the annotation in question: (@RequiresPrivileges)

```
  @RequiresPrivileges(value = {PrivilegeType.USRMGA, PrivilegeType.USRMGO}, usrMgmntObj = User.class, usrMgmntObjId = userDto.getId()) // at this stage, userDto is not known
  @PutMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<DetailedUserDto>> update(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.update(userDto), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

@interface RequiresPrivileges:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface RequiresPrivileges {

  /**
   * Required privileges to access the method
   */
  PrivilegeType[] value();

  /**
   * If user wants to make changes to another user or usergroup, the rank needs to be checked. To do so,
   * the object class (user or usergroup) and the suiting id needs to be provided
   */
  Class usrMgmntObj() default Object.class;
  long usrMgmntObjId() default -1;
}
```

@Aspect of the Annotation

```
@Around("@annotation(RequiresPrivileges)")
public Object requiresPrivileges(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

  MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
  Method method = signature.getMethod();

  PrivilegeType[] privileges = method.getAnnotation(RequiresPrivileges.class).value();
  Class usrMgmntObjClass = method.getAnnotation(RequiresPrivileges.class).usrMgmntObj();
  long usrMgmntObjId = method.getAnnotation(RequiresPrivileges.class).usrMgmntObjId();

  boolean authorized = false;

  // if the user wants to change a user management object (user or usergroup), the rank has to be higher than the
  // one the user wants to change. BUT user with the privilege PrivilegeType.USRMGA may edit without checking the
  // rank
  if ((usrMgmntObjClass == User.class || usrMgmntObjClass == Usergroup.class) && usrMgmntObjId > -1) {

    if (usrMgmntObjClass == User.class) {
      if (!authorizationService.hasHigherRank(currentUserService.getCurrentUserId(), usrMgmntObjId)) {
        if (authorizationService.hasPrivileges(privileges, currentUserService.getCurrentUserId())) {
          // user is authorized
          authorized = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // check for privileges if user is not authorized already
  if (!authorized) {
    if (authorizationService.hasPrivileges(privileges, currentUserService.getCurrentUserId())) {
      // user is authorized
      return joinPoint.proceed();
    } else {
      // user is not authorized
      throw new AccessNotAllowedException(currentUserService.getCurrentUserId());
    }
  } else {
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

How can I pass the ID of the `UserDto` (or the whole object) to the annotation? Is it possible to create another annotation for the parameter `userDto` with `ElementType.PARAMETER` and perform the logic there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing your own annotations, if your application uses Spring Security then you could simply use Spring's `@PreAuthorize`. Else, if you wan't to do it the way you are doing now then you can get the `UserDto` from method's argument using `JoinPoint#getArgs()`.

Comment: Thank you, `JoinPoint#getArgs()` is what I needed.